# Can I test if MS Access 2003 startup options were executed/bypassed?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have configured startup options in a MS Access 2003 database in such a way that my main form called `application` will appear on startup. I know I can bypass these startup options by holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> upon opening the file.

However, I have the following code on this main form `application`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Close
  DoCmd.Quit
End Sub
```

which I would like to bypass when I am in editing mode, as it currently exits MS Access in editing mode as well (meaning when I view the actual form having bypassed the startup options, not when viewing the form in design mode).

Is there a way, in VBA, to detect whether the startup options were executed/bypassed?

Comment: What about a hidden startup from instead? it is not visible, so no form design is necessary. Just used for running code at startup or close. And if you use the `Form_Unload`event you can add confirmation dialog and cancel if wanted.

Comment: @BitAccesser Those are great suggestions. Thanks! Although it's not specifically what I was looking for, you could still put it in an answer and I would upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden startup form (hide with `Me.Visible = False` on `Form_Load`), which doesn't need design. Then use the `Form_Unload(Cancel as Integer)` event and you can add a confirmation dialog too.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Do you really want to quit?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        ' do something before quit, but Form_Close will raise too
    End If
End Sub
```

The startup form could be used to trigger shift on startup as it is not loaded (unless you start it elsewhere), if shift is used, what you can detect.

Be aware of not closing the form accidentally (e.g. in a close all open forms function).

Comment: Can I set the form to hidden in the properties dialog somewhere, perhaps? I can't seem to find it. Or do I need to do this with VBA in `Form_Load` (or somewhere similar) perhaps? I know this can be done with `Me.Visible = False`, for instance.